# Condition is not resolved as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, kernel, marshalling

I'm using this library to get the amount of free disk space:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(string lpDirectoryName, out ulong lpFreeBytesAvailable, out ulong lpTotalNumberOfBytes, out ulong lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes);
```

I use it in the method as:

```
var result = GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(desiredInstallLocation, out var freeBytesAvailable, out var totalNumberOfBytes, out var totalNumberOfFreeBytes);
```

Then the condition comes to the play:

```
if (gameSize > (int)freeBytesAvailable)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"There is not enough disk space!\nYou need to free at least {ConvertBytesToMegabytes(gameSize - (int)freeBytesAvailable)} MB.", "Not enough space on a disk", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error, MessageBoxResult.OK);
    return false;
}
```

Here is the record from the debugging:

[image]

[image]

Why is the condiiton passed?

Comment: Try  casting to the larger type, i.e. `if ((long)gameSize > freeBytesAvailable)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cast `freeBytesAvailable` to `int`, but it is a `ulong`. The value returned by `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` is `377,325,965,312` exceeds the maximum value of `int` (`2,147,483,647`).

Therefore, the least 32-Bits of the `ulong` are taken for the down-casted `int` and in your case that is a negative number, because its most significant bit is `1`. Hence, the condition will be `true`.

```
11011010011000010101000000000000 (-631156736)
```

Instead, cast the `gameSize` to `ulong`, so you do not lose information.

```
if ((ulong)gameSize > freeBytesAvailable)
```

Comment: That was the case. Isn't that strange that debbuger was showing `377325965312` instead of `-631156736`?

Comment: @Chyuae No, it is not strange. The debugger is just showing you the value of  `freeBytesAvailable`, not `(int)freeBytesAvailable`. If you create a local variable for it, you will see. Casting the variable does not change the value of `freeBytesAvailable`.